# Double Hardened Scales

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-heroic

I'm having issues understanding how a possible turn would go which I'll try to explain best I can.

Say I currently had two [Battlewise Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlewise%20Hoplite)s currently on the board. One of them currently has [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales) but the other does not. This would mean that the first which has the enchantment would have two +1/+1 counters currently. The first for its Heroic ability and another due to Hardened Scales.

Now say that I decide that I want to play an additional Hardened Scales to the other Battlewise that isn't enchanted and is still a 2/2? I'm unclear how two Hardened scales on the board at the same time would resolve?

I'm still pretty new to magic so excuse me if I'm using wrong terminology!

Thanks!

Comment: Hardened Scales is not an aura - it is a generic enchantment that stays on the battlefield and has a "global" effect.

Comment: So to clarify what @HaoYe said, in the situation you described neither Hoplite should have had any counters at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all enchantments attach to a creature (or any kind of permanent). In general, enchantments just sit on the battlefield like artifacts. *Auras* are special types of enchantments that *do* attach to things. They have a type line that says "Enchantment - Aura" and an ability in the text box that says "Enchant [object]," which means that it attaches to objects with the given description.

Hardened Scales doesn't target, and it doesn't just affect just one creature. As long as it's on the battlefield, any time you would put any number of +1/+1 counters on **any** creature you control, you also put an extra +1/+1 counter on that creature.

If you had two copies of Hardened Scales, every time you put +1/+1 counters on one of your creatures, each of the abilities modifies what happens and you add two extra counters.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! This works out better than I was even hoping!

Comment: One important thing to note here is that playing your Hardened Scales doesn't cause any creature to get +1/+1 counters because it doesn't target them.

Comment: Just so I'm clear: If I were to have Hardened Scales and a Battlewise Hoplite on the board then played a creature enchantment onto the hoplite, it would get +2/+2 due to its +1/+1 it normally gets and the Hardened Scales adding an additional counter. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it would get a single +1/+1 counter due to it's ability, and Hardened scales would add another counter, for a total of 2 +1/+1 counters.